# Azure Data Factory (ADF) - Concur Connector Authentication Issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Has anyone able to create a Linked Service in between Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Concur (preview) connector, because whenever i try to create a Linked Service I get this error.

ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Concur] (1017) Malformed response received from Authentication server that lacks following information: "Auth_AccessToken" located at "Access_Token.Token" from the server response; "Auth_RefreshToken" located at "Access_Token.Refresh_Token" from the server response; "Auth_Expires" located at "Access_Token.Expiration_date" from the server response.

To see error picture click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu96y.png)

Comment: How exactly is it that you are creating the Linked Service? You should be more specific if you expect anyone to help.

The error also seems to hint at an authorization error.

Comment: Hi @pijemcolu , actually i'm creating a linked service in Azure Data Factory(V2) for a Cocur connector (it a connector in ADF to connect with SAP Concur), in which we will pass Username, Password and ClientId  to sign in but whenever i pass all the details(i.e username, password and clientID) and test the connectio, i get the error as mentioned above